# Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed

Tags: reactjs, url, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, createobjecturl

I want to add an image upload feature to my website. If the image is uploaded I want it to be displayed in an IMG tag otherwise shows the first letter of the username. So to check whether the image is uploaded or not, I created a field in my firestore named **userImageUpload**. I stored the firestore details in a state **userDetails** and if I call **userDetails.data()** I will get the fields of the user document.

To check if image uploaded, I added this code:

```
           {userDetails.data().userImageUpload ? (
              <img src={URL.createObjectURL(image)} alt="" />
            ) : (
              <h1>B</h1>
            )}
          </div>
```

But I am getting the  error as :
**TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed**